# Is there a difference between [class]="'success'" and class="success" in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

In Angular is there a difference between `[class]="'success'"` and `class="success"`?

So for example:

```
 <li class="success">...</li>
```

or

```
 <li [class]="'success'">...</li>
```

IIUC the latter will cause the replacement of the former if both are used at the same time, so I'm trying to better understand why we would not just use the first one?

Comment: In general there's no difference between `[attribute]="'value'"` and `attribute="value"`, you can use either if you have a static string value.

Answer (score 3):

The first one (`class`) is just a html class attribute.
The latter (`[class]`) is actually an angular binding, meaning that whatever is in it will be parsed just like any other angular binding (you can put angular/javascript expressions in it).

You are fine to use `class` if the classes doesn't need to change. Use `[class]` if you plan to change them. You can even mix them up, like:

```
<li class="success" [class.active]="true">...</li>
```